# Using Phonegap on Android, emails array returns null for contacts.find

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am getting a null value returned for contacts that do have an email address. I am testing on Android 4.1.1 and am able to access other attributes such as givenName and familyName. The Phonegap version is 2.9. And, I don't see emails listed in the Quirks section of the Phonegap API Documentation for Android.

```
function populateContactInfo(num){
    $('#input-first').val(contacts[num].name.givenName);
    $('#input-last').val(contacts[num].name.familyName);
    if(contacts[num].emails){
       $('#input-email').val(contacts[num].emails[0]);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: `emails` must be specified in the fields array in order for the data to be returned.

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = val;
options.multiple=true;
var fields = ["name","displayName","emails"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onFindContacts, onError, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the `value` attribute of the email address, like this:

```
function populateContactInfo(num){
    $('#input-first').val(contacts[num].name.givenName);
    $('#input-last').val(contacts[num].name.familyName);
    if(contacts[num].emails){
       $('#input-email').val(contacts[num].emails[0].value);
    }
};
```